# cant change variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a navigation area and am trying to switch tabs with the active variable.
This is just for the nav button, but later I'd like to make a rotator too by switching the variable.

Here is my code:

```
                active = 1;

        function hover() {


            $(nav1).live('mouseenter', function() {
                active = 2;
            });

            if ( active == 1) {
            $(tab1).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            else if ( active != 1) {
                $(tab1).fadeOut('slow');
            } 

            if ( active == 2) {
                $(tab2).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            else if ( active != 2) {
                $(tab2).fadeOut('slow');
            } 

        }


        hover();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include *an actual question*. What isn't working? What errors do you get? What *question* do you want us to answer? Stack Overflow is about *questions* and answers, and if your question doesn't contain a question mark, then it isn't a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

```
active = 1;
function showTab() {
    if ( active == 1) {
        $(tab1).fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else if ( active != 1) {
        $(tab1).fadeOut('slow');
    } 

    if ( active == 2) {
        $(tab2).fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else if ( active != 2) {
        $(tab2).fadeOut('slow');
    }
}

$(nav1).live('hover', function() {
    active = 1;
    showTab();
});

$(nav2).live('hover', function() {
    active = 2;
    showTab();
});
```

Note that you need four vars tab1, tab2, nav1 and nav2 for this code.

Comment: It is called whenever $(nav1) and $(nav2) are hovered (see code below the function).

Answer (score 0):

Your tab selection "if ( active == 1) {..." is only called at the beginning. You'll need to call this switch loop again.

Because of your question if active equals 2 - obviously it does not. Do you mean

```
$(nav1).live('hover', function() {
   active += 1;
});
```

This increases active every time you hover $(nav1). By the way: Do you mean $('nav1')?

Comment: sorry, had a mistake in there.. now ive added a row for nav2 and tab2...

the active = 1; at the beginning is just to have a start image

Comment: it just doesnt change the variable when i hover.. it does everything else, like change opacity on hover or nething else.

Comment: Active is a very common name. Probably there is a naming conflict with other JS code?

Comment: ive changed the var , doesnt work still.. also i dont want it to go up 1 i just want to change it to 2 :S

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, then you might think about setting the 'active' variable to the actual menu item instead of a number.  Also, you might be using jQuery .live() incorrectly and in addition, jQuery .delegate() is probably more useful in this case depending on your markup.  (see jquery.com for info on these methods)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

// the active nav item:
var active;

// set up the hover events on each nav item only after the DOM is ready:
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.nav li').hover(function() {

        // set the active nav item:
        active = $(this);

        // show the active nav item in the UI as test
        alert(this.id);
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav">
    <li id="nav1">nav 1</li>
    <li id="nav2">nav 1</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're trying to get the index value of the active menu item, then you could replace active = $(this); with active = $(this).index(); and then to test just use alert(active);